# COUNT(DISTINCT) in subquery

Tags: sql, distinct

I am trying to retrieve each loan number, with the count of how many times the loan number appears in each month.  So in some cases the loan number appears twice in the month, but I just want it to be counted once in each month. TEST and RD columns are not giving me what I need.  Here is what I have:

```
select 
[Month],
one,
LoanNumber,
two,
three,
four,
...

count(distinct LoanNumber) as TEST,
COUNT(LoanNumber) OVER () as RD

from

tableNAME LC
where [month] ='12-2016'
group by 
[Month],
one,
LoanNumber,
two,
three,
four,
...
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to add a `partition by` clause to your windowing count() expression, and remove the `group by`, like this:

```
select 
[Month],
one,
LoanNumber,
two,
three,
four,
...
COUNT(*) OVER (partition by Month, LoanNumber) as NumberOfOccurences

from

tableNAME LC
where [month] ='12-2016'
```

Comment: hi.  i kinda thought it might involve that, but its not working

Comment: edited to remove group by.  This will work if you want to see all the rows (including the various values for columns "one", "two", "three", etc.), but the count itself will be repeated - this is the price you pay for preserving all the detail but getting the summary.  If you just want the summary, then a simple `select Month, LoanNumber, COUNT(*) from TableName where Month = '12-2016' group by Month, LoanNumber` would work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take LoanNumber out of your GROUP BY clause.

Also, take it out of your SELECT clause, if you want to group by month, and not each loanNumber within the month.

Comment: thanks.  looks like it works just fine if i take the LoanNumber out of the SELECT.  So are you saying that I can either show LoanNumber and have the NumberOfOccurences be bloated, or NOT show the LoanNumber and have it be correct?

Comment: for each field, you either want to group by it or you don't.  if you want to group independently of loanNumber, you don't include it in the select or group by clauses, and you apply an aggregate function to it like count(distinct loannumber).  Not seeing where you're referencing 'numberOfOccurences'

Comment: sorry, just saw it in the response above.  You don't need it, count(distinct loanNumber) grouped by month will get you there.